# $\cos (\cos x) > \sin (\sin x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\ \cos (\cos x) > \sin (\sin x)$

I've tried the obvious thing to do:

$\varphi: x \mapsto \cos(\cos x) - \sin (\sin x)$

$\varphi ' (x) = \sin (\cos x) \sin x - \cos(\sin x) \cos x$

I'd like to show now that $\varphi$ is a positive function for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but the derivative does not look friendly so either there's something with $\varphi '$. I'm not seeing or it's not the right way. Any hint or idea?

Comment: Letting $u=\sin x$ then you want to show that $\cos(\sqrt{1-u^2})>\sin(u)$ for all $u\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews And then for $\sqrt{1-u^2}\in[0,1]$, since $1<\pi/2$, we have $\cos(\sqrt{1-u^2})>\cos(\pi/2)=0$.  For $u\in[-1,0]$, $0>\sin(u)$, so it comes down to looking at $u\in(0,1]$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We know that $|\sin(x)|<|x|$, which I assume is taken to be known, since you differentiated $\sin(x)$. Hence, it follows from this and Pythagorean identities that

$$\cos^2(\cos(x))=1-\sin^2(\cos(x))>1-\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x)$$

$$\sin^2(\sin(x))<\sin^2(x)$$

Thus, it follows that

$$\cos^2(\cos(x))>\sin^2(x)>\sin^2(\sin(x))$$

And since $\cos(\cos(x))\in[\cos(1),1]\implies\cos(\cos(x))>0$ and $a^2>b^2\implies|a|>|b|\ge b$, it follows that

$$\cos^2(\cos(x))>\sin^2(\sin(x))\\\implies|\cos(\cos(x))|>|\sin(\sin(x))|\ge\sin(\sin(x))$$

Comment: To think it comes down so simply!  :D

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think the argument could do with some more prose to explain the roles of the various inequalities. Some of them are statements you want to prove, others are things you already know, and it's not really clear which are which.

Comment: The downvote is mine: $a^2 > b^2$ doesn't give $a > b$. Unless you have a good argument to fix this issue, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Cauchy: The only case where one of the sides of the goal _can_ be negative is if $\sin(x)<0$, and then the inequality _obviously_ holds, so the argument is not needed at all.

Comment: @Cauchy Yeah, as I've mentioned in comments on the main post, $\cos(\cos(x))>0$, and $\sin(\sin(x))$ is an odd function.

Comment: Aha, now I see. Perhaps you can mention that bit in the post so it's edited and I can remove my vote.

Comment: @Cauchy Yeah, I am :-) Plus a bit of tidying up.

Comment: @Cauchy Perhaps it looks better now?  :-)

Comment: Yes, nicely done! :)

Comment: @Cauchy Actually, I think I made it a bit clearer at the end with the inequalities, if you'd care.

Answer (score 4):

We need to prove that
$$\cos\cos{x}-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}\right)>0$$ or
$$2\sin\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}-\cos{x}}{2}\sin\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{2}>0,$$
which is true because
By C-S $$\sin{x}\pm\cos{x}\leq\sqrt{(1^2+1^2)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)}=\sqrt2<\frac{\pi}{2},$$
which gives
$$0<\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}\pm\cos{x}}{2}<\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+\sqrt2}{2}<\pi$$

Comment: Can someone explain we your down vote?

Comment: It looks good to me, and as economical as anything could be. The missing steps are easy to fill in.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg can you explain to me why $\frac{\pi}{2} - \sin x - \cos x > 0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} - \sin x + \cos x > 0$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If that holds i guess we could say the following: suppose there exists $x$ such that $\cos (\cos x) = \sin (\sin x) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - \sin x)$. Then,  $\cos x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin x$ or $\cos x = -\frac{\pi}{2} + \sin x$ (mod $2\pi$) which is false and since $f: x \mapsto \cos (\cos x) - \sin (\sin x)$ is continuous, either $f > 0$ or $f < 0$ and with $f( x = 0)$ we could conclude right?

Comment: @Wylex I used that  $\sin{x}>0$ for $0<x<\pi$. Also, I used $\cos{x}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ and $\cos\alpha-\cos\beta=2\sin\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$. See better, please, my solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\sin(x))=\cos(\pi/2-\sin(x))$, write $f(x)=\pi/2-\sin(x)-\cos(x)$, $f'(x)=-\cos(x)+\sin(x)$, we study $f$ in $[0,\pi/2]$, $f'(x)=0$ implies $x=\pi/4$, $f(\pi/4)>0$ $f(0)>0, f(\pi/2)>0$, implies that $f$ decreases from $0$ to $\pi/4$ and increases from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$, and $f>0$ on $[0,\pi/2]$.

this implies that $\pi/2-\sin(x)>\cos(x)$, since $\cos$ decreases on $[0,\pi/2]$ we deduce that $\cos(\cos(x))>\cos(\pi/2-\sin(x))=\sin(\sin(x))$.